# Can all $n$-dimensional real Lie algebras be considered as $\mathbb{R}^n$ with particular Lie bracket?

Tags: vector-spaces, lie-algebras

Since all $n$-dimensional real vector spaces are isomorphic (as vector spaces) to $\mathbb{R}^n$, can all $n$-dimensional real Lie algebras be reconfigured as $(\mathbb{R}^n,[\cdot,\cdot])$, where the important feature is the Lie bracket, rather than the underlying vector space?

In other words, if $(V,[\cdot,\cdot]_1)$ is any $n$-dimensional real Lie algebra, is it true that it is isomorphic (as a Lie algebra) to $(\mathbb{R}^n,[\cdot,\cdot]_2)$ for some Lie bracket $[\cdot,\cdot]_2$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Yes, this is true. Just rewrite the brackets in the standard basis of $\Bbb R^n$, using the isomorphism between $V$ and $\Bbb R^n$. For the definition of a Lie algebra, the ground field $K$ is important. Then we may assume that the Lie algebra is $K^n$ as vector space.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is true.

---

## First approach

Let more generally $(\mathfrak{g}, [-,-]_1)$ be a Lie algebra over some field $K$.
If $\mathfrak{h}$ is a $K$-vector space of the same dimension as $\mathfrak{g}$ then there exists an isomorphism of vector spaces
$$
  \varphi
  \colon
  \mathfrak{h}
  \to
  \mathfrak{g} \,.
$$
We can use this isomorphism of vector spaces to pull back the Lie bracket on $\mathfrak{g}$ to a Lie bracket on $\mathfrak{h}$.
More precisely, we set
$$
  [x, y]_2
  :=
  \varphi^{-1}( [ \varphi(x), \varphi(y) ]_1 )
$$
for all $x, y \in \mathfrak{h}$.
This defines a Lie bracket on $\mathfrak{h}$, and the vector space isomorphism $\varphi$ becomes an isomorphism of Lie algebras
$$
  \varphi
  \colon
  ( \mathfrak{h}, [-,-]_2 )
  \to
  ( \mathfrak{g}, [-,-]_1 ) \,.
$$
(This Lie bracket $[-,-]_2$ is the unique Lie bracket on $\mathfrak{h}$ which makes $\varphi$ into an isomorphism of Lie algebras.)

Suppose now that $K = \mathbb{R}$ and that the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is of finite dimension $n$.
If $x_1, \dotsc, x_n$ is a basis of $\mathfrak{g}$ then we get an isomorphism of vector spaces
$$
  \varphi
  \colon
  \mathbb{R}^n
  \to
  \mathfrak{g} \,,
  \quad
  e_i
  \mapsto
  x_i
  \qquad
  \text{for all $i = 1, \dotsc, n$,}
$$
where $e_1, \dotsc, e_n$ denotes the standard basis of $\mathfrak{g}$.
As explained above we can pull back the Lie bracket $[-,-]_1$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ to a Lie bracket $[-,-]_2$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\varphi$ becomes an isomorphism of Lie algebras.

---

## Second approach

There is also a less abstract but equivalent way of explaining the above procedure.
Suppose again that $(\mathfrak{g}, [-,-]_1)$ is a Lie algebra over a field $K$ and let $x_1, \dotsc, x_n$ be a basis of $\mathfrak{g}$.
We can then consider the structure constants of $[-,-]_1$ with respect to the basis $x_1, \dotsc, x_n$.
These are the unique coefficients $c_{ij}^k \in K$ with
$$
  [x_i, x_j] = \sum_{k=1}^n c_{ij}^k x_k
$$
for all $i, j = 1, \dotsc, n$.
That $[-,-]_1$ is a Lie bracket on $\mathfrak{g}$ is equivalent to the conditions
\begin{equation}
  c_{ii}^\ell = 0 \,,
  \quad
  c_{ij}^\ell + c_{ji}^\ell = 0 \,,
  \quad
  \sum_{k=1}^n
  ( c_{ij}^k c_{k \ell}^m + c_{j \ell}^k c_{ki}^m + c_{\ell i}^k c_{kj}^m ) = 0
  \tag{1}
\end{equation}
for all $i, j, \ell, m = 1, \dotsc, n$.
If we are now given another $K$-vector space $\mathfrak{h}$ with basis $y_1, \dotsc, y_n$ then we can define a unique bilinear map
$$
  [-,-]_2
  \colon
  \mathfrak{h} \times \mathfrak{h}
  \to
  \mathfrak{h}
$$
such that
$$
  [y_i, y_j]
  :=
  \sum_{k=1}^n c_{ij}^k y_k
$$
for all $i,j = 1, \dotsc, n$.
The structure constants of $[-,-]_2$ with respect to the basis $y_1, \dotsc, y_n$ of $\mathfrak{h}$ are (by construction) the same as the structure constants of $[-,-]_1$ with respect to the basis $x_1, \dotsc, x_n$ of $\mathfrak{g}$.
It follows that $[-,-]_2$ is a Lie bracket on $\mathfrak{h}$ since the conditions $(1)$ are satisfied.
Moreover, there exists a unique linear map $\varphi$ from $\mathfrak{h}$ to $\mathfrak{g}$ with
$$
  \varphi(y_i) = x_i
$$
for all $i = 1, \dotsc, n$, and this linear map is an isomorphism of Lie algebras from $(\mathfrak{h}, [-,-]_2)$ to $(\mathfrak{g}, [-,-]_1)$.

In the given situation we have $K = \mathbb{R}$ and can choose $\mathfrak{h} = \mathbb{R}^n$ and for $y_1, \dotsc, y_n$ the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.